# Multi-core processor for multiple data containers

Tags: multicore

I have a dual core Intel processor and would like to use one core for processing certain commands like SATA writes and another for reads, how do we do it? Can this be controlled from the application(with multiple threads) or would this require a change in the kernel to ensure the reads/writes dont get processed by the the 'wrong' core?

Answer (score 0):

This will be pretty much totally up to your operating system, which you haven't specified.

Some may offer thread affinity to try and keep one thread on the same execution engine (be that a core or a CPU), but that's only for threads. If two threads both write to disk, then they may well do so on different engines.

If you want that sort of low level control, it's probably best to do it at the kernel level.

My question to you would by "Why?". A great deal of performance tuning goes into OS kernels and they would generally know better than any application how to efficiently do this low level stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are thinking about using Linux.And the reason I want to do low level control is per some security specifications to keep certain operations contained to a particular engine.